# How to create pretrained word embedding text file with additional word features

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embeddings, gensim

I've had an idea for using word features to improve the quality of neural machine translation. Now, I would like to create word embeddings with additional word features such as pos tag, named entity, lemma, etc. I used gensim to create pretrained word embeddings and pretrained tag embeddings. However, I still do not understand how to deal with it.  Are there any ways to implement this idea? Should I annotated pos tag on a training data file and train a new word embedding model with it?